# Query child posts with tax query on parents

Tags: wp-query, woocommerce-offtopic, tax-query

I have this WP_Query:

```
                new WP_Query(
                        array(
                            'post_type' => 'product_variation',
                            'post_status'       => 'publish',
                            'posts_per_page'    => -1,
                            'tax_query' => array(
                                array(
                                    'taxonomy' => 'product_cat',
                                    'field'    => 'slug',
                                    'terms'    => array( 'archive', 'membership' ),
                                    'operator' => 'NOT IN',
                                ),
                            ),
                            'fields' => 'ids',
                        )
                    );
```

The problem is, that the `product_cat` taxonomy is set on the parent products, not the variations. Meaning, I need to get all the variations whose *parents* are not in the specified categories, or in other words: get child posts but run the tax query on the parent posts.

I know this can be achieved with MySQL, but I was wondering if there's a clean way of doing it with WP_Query.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My solution to this ended up splitting this into 2 queries:

1. Get the IDs of all the parent products I want to ignore
2. Get all the variations that don't a post_parent from that list of IDs

   ```
   $archived_products = wc_get_products(
       array(
           'type' => array( 'variable', 'variable-subscription' ),
           'paginate' => false,
           'limit' => -1,
           'category' => array( 'archive', 'membership' ),
           'return' => 'ids',
       )
   );
   $my_query->set( 'post_parent__not_in', $archived_products );
   ```